# jQuery loop and append dynamic list on keyup

Tags: jquery, list, keyup

I'm trying to build a simple form with two fields: `label` and `value`. After filling in those fields the user should hit the `Enter` key and two more fields (label and value) should appear. This far I managed to get everything to work fine. Now, I need the input-data from each label and value field to populate an unordered list.

As far as I figured out the pseudo-code should be something like this: if the `Enter` key is pressed create two new text fields (label and value), copy the input-data and display it inside an `li` element; then repeat.

The code I tried is below, I'm missing a loop on the `keyup` function but even without it the `li` elements don't show up only after I create two new fields and I go back to edit the first two (check the [JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SSjBg/2/)). I did tried to code a loop on this function but everything failed so I thought about posting here, maybe I'm looking at this all wrong.

This is the HTML code:

```
<button id="addChart">Add Chart Label and Value</button>
<div id="label">
    <p>
        <label for="label">
            <input type="text" id="labelrow" size="20" name="label" value="" placeholder="Input Label" />
        </label>
        <label for="value">
            <input type="text" id="valuerow" size="20" name="value" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
<ul class="jrGraph">
    <li>
        <span class="label"></span>
        <span class="value"></span>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the jQuery script:

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#label');
    var i = $('#label p').size() + 1;

    $('#addChart').on('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="label"><input type="text" id="labelrow" size="20" name="label_' + i + '<p><label for="value"><input type="text" id="valuerow" size="20" name="value_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#label').keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#addChart').click();
            $("#labelrow").on("keyup change", function () {
                $('span.label').text(this.value);
            });
            $("#valuerow").on("keyup change", function () {
                $('span.value').text(this.value);
            });
        }
    });

    $('#label').on('click', '.remScnt', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

and [JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SSjBg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following, though I suspect it can be optimised:

```
$('#label').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var self = e.target,
        $self = $(self),
        target = $('.jrGraph').first();
    if (e.which === 13 && self.id === 'labelrow') {
        $self.closest('label')
            .next().find('input').focus();
    } else if (e.which === 13) {
        var label = $('#labelrow'),
            val = $('#valuerow'),
            li = $('<li />').appendTo(target);
        $('<span />', {
            'class' : 'label',
            text: label.val()
        }).appendTo(li);
        $('<span />', {
            'class' : 'value',
            text: val.val()
        }).appendTo(li);
        label.val('').focus();
        val.val('');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/srasB/1/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/).
- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).